# SAPUI5 - Create model with '0' value

Tags: sapui5

I'm creating model instances in a for loop ( 0 - 6 )...

Everything works fine apart from when DayOfWeek = 0, in which case a default value is entered into the model, not the correct value of 0.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 7 ; i++) {
  var oEntry = {};
  oEntry.DayOfWeek = i;

  oModel.create("/CalendarSet", oEntry, {
    success : success,
    error : error
  });

  oModel.submitChanges(success, error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
var oModelOData = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel();

for (var i = 0; i < 7 ; i++) {
    oEntry.DayOfWeek = i;
    oModel.setProperty("/CalendarSet", oEntry);
    oModelOData.setProperty("/CalendarSet", oEntry);
});
```

Btw. to use submit changes you need an OData Model V2, simply change `sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel` to `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel`, everything else stays the same.